# Confusion about HTTP transferring non-text (binary) data

Tags: javascript, json, http, networking, base64

I was looking at this MDN tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages
where it says

> HTTP messages are composed of textual information encoded in ASCII.

I thought it means that HTTP can only transfer textual info aka strings, assuming the HTTP message here refers to header + body in responses.

But later I found out that HTTP response body can have multiple MIME types outside of text, such as image, video, application/json etc. Doesn't that mean HTTP can also transfer non-textual information, which contradicts what that MDN page says about HTTP messages?

I am aware of encoding methods like utf-8 and base64, I guess you can use Base64 Encoding for the binary data so that it is transformed into text — and then can be sent with an application/json content type as another property of the JSON payload. But when you choose not to do encoding, instead using correct `content-type` you can just transfer the binary data? I am  still trying to figure this out.

Also I have some experience consuming REST APIs from the front end. My impression is that you typically don't transfer any binary data e.g. images, files, audios with RESTful APIs. They often serve JSON or XML as the response. I wonder why is that? Is it because REST APIs is not suitable for transferring binary data directly? What are some of the common practice for transferring images or audios files to the front end?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you quoted is talking about the start line, status line, and headers, which use only ASCII.

The body of a request or response is an arbitrary sequence of bytes. It's mainly intepreted by the application, not by the HTTP layer. It doesn't need to be in any particular encoding. The header has a `Content-Length` field, and the client simply reads that many bytes after the header (there's also *chunked* encoding, which breaks the content up into chunks, but each one starts with a byte length, and the client simply concatenates them).

In addition, HTTP includes [`Transfer-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) types that specify the encoding of the data. This includes a number of compression formats that produce binary data.

While it's possible to use textual encodings such as base64, this is not usually done in HTTP because it increases the size of the message and it's not necessary.

Comment: Yea I know base64 increase the size of the message but then how do you transfer images through HTTP protocol then?

Comment: `Content-Length` specifies the number of bytes. It just reads that many bytes after the header.

Comment: sorry that doesn't really answer my question. I am still not sure how we can transfer an image or audio file via HTTP. Is there any encoding / decoding happening outside of gzipping if we are not using base64? Or we can just transfer binary data wit the right content-type?

Comment: You just transfer binary data.

Comment: Use a packet capture tool like Wireshark and you'll see it.